# Count elements in a list that show up in another list

Tags: r, list

I have a list composed of proteins (characters) and the proteins they interact with, and a vector of proteins that constitutes a cluster (vector of characters). I want to build a list of data.frames counting the number of times that the elements of the vector of characters appear in each element of the list,

Please find here a summary of my data for an explanatory example:

```
>list1
$ENSG00000206212
[1] "SNORA70"         "RPS27"           "HIST1H3F"        "RPL37"           "ENSG00000196656" "EIF4E"           "EIF3I"           "FAU"            
[9] "EIF4H"           "ENSG00000206212" "WDR3"            "HIST1H4C"        "EIF3C"           "SNORD33"         "RPS12"           "HIST1H4B"       
[17] "RPL39"           "ENSG00000173534" "RPL7"            "HIST1H3I"        "HSPA5"           "NOL6"            "RPL17P39"        "ENSG00000182498"
[25] "RPL30"           "ENO1"            "EMG1"            "RPL8"            "RPS27A"          "RPL26"           "BOP1"            "NOC4L"          
[33] "HIST1H3D"        "IDH3A"           "YBX1"            "LOC100505503"    "EIF3J"           "RPL35A"          "PDCD11"          "ENSG00000182953"
[41] "RPS11"           "HIST1H4J"        "DDX27"           "HIST1H4D"        "ATP5A1"          "ENSG00000204221" "RPL29"           "CAMK2D"         
[49] "WDR74"           "ENSG00000183311" "ENSG00000206284" "ENSG00000175333" "HIST1H2BE"       "RPS20"           "RPS7P1"          "RPL36"          
[57] "KRR1"            "HNRNPH1"         "HEATR1"          "SLC25A4"         "HIST1H2BI"       "TBK1"            "RPL11"           "UTP20"          
[65] "RPL3L"           "PRPF19"          "MYL6"            "RPS14"           "RPS17"           "EIF3K"           "RPL18"           "BXDC2"          
[73] "ENSG00000187899" "RPL27AP"         "HNRNPK"          "HIST1H3H"        "DDX5"            "HIST1H2AB"       "CAPZB"           "S100A6"         
[81] "HIST1H4H"        "RPS19"           "BXDC5"           "PHB"             "EIF5A"           "MYL12A"          "ENSG00000206212" "DECR1"          
[89] "RPL27"           "RPL15P3"         "HIST2H4B"        "DDX18"           "WIZ"             "RPL4"            "TUBB2C"          "RPS5"           
[97] "NOP14"           "ENSG00000198637" "RPL34"           "ENSG00000138396" "EIF3B"           "HIST1H2BH"       "RUVBL2"          "FTSJ3"          
[105] "EIF4A1"          "HIST1H2BG"       "EIF2S3"          "EIF3E"           "HIST1H4K"        "HSPA8"           "IMP3"            "UTP15"          
[113] "RRP9"            "RPL13AP25"       "IMP4"            "RPL21P28"        "SNORD55"         "PWP2"            "ENSG00000197303" "EIF4A3"         
[121] "RPS13"           "BYSL"            "FBL"             "RPS3"            "RPL38"           "HIST1H2AE"       "NFKB2"           "HIST1H4I"                

$SNORD24
[1] "HIST1H2AI"       "RPLP2"           "ENSG00000130041" "RPL27"           "RPL26"           "RPS15"           "RPL9"            "YBX1"           
[9] "ENSG00000196656" "RPL15P3"         "HIST1H2AL"       "RPS4Y1"          "RPS26"           "RPL14"           "RPS19"           "EEF1A1P9"       
[17] "RPLP1"           "RPL12"           "SF3B3"           "GRINL1B"         "BXDC2"           "LAS1L"           "DDX27"           "SSRP1"          
[25] "DDX5"            "WDR12"           "ENSG00000173534" "RPS4X"           "EIF3I"           "RPL7"            "RPS26P2"         "ENSG00000182498"
[33] "RPL39"           "RPLP0"           "DDX18"           "RPL28"           "HNRNPA1"                  

$ENSG00000187899
[1] "EMG1"            "WDR3"            "RPL8"            "ENSG00000182498" "ENSG00000206212" "SNORD33"         "CIRH1A"          "LARP2"          
[9] "ENSG00000187899" "RPL17P39"        "SNORA70"         "UTP11L"          "NOL6"            "LOC100130702"    "RPL30"           "ENSG00000174766"
[17] "MPHOSPH10"       "RSL1D1"          "RPL18"           "ENSG00000096150" "RPL4"            "UTP20"           "RPS4X"           "PRPF19"         
[25] "RBM19"           "RPL27AP"         "PDCD11"          "KRR1"            "IMP4"            "ENSG00000204221" "IMP3"            "RRP9"           
[33] "FBL"             "RPL3"            "HSP90AB1"        "EIF5A"           "RPS19"           "TBL3"            "RPS15"           "SNORD4A"        
[41] "AATF"            "RPL19"           "ENSG00000007816" "NOP58"           "RPLP0"           "RIOK2"           "DHX37"           "WDSOF1"         
[49] "MKI67IP"         "SMARCB1"         "RPL10A"          "ENSG00000138396" "RPL15P3"         "RPS17"           "SNORD73A"        "RPL14"          
[57] "RPL18A"          "NOL10"           "ENSG00000175333" "RPL7P"           "ENSG00000187899" "RPL18AP11"       "PSMD4"           "RPL9"           
[65] "PNO1"            "RPS5"            "RPL13AP25"       "NAF1"            "RPL14P1"                   

$RPLP2
[1] "RPLP2"           "SSPO"            "EEF2"            "ENSG00000182498" "MAP3K14"         "DDX55"           "RPL30"           "RPL17P39"       
[9] "RPS29"           "HIST1H4B"        "RPL12"           "RPS12"           "SNORA70"         "MT3"             "PKM2"            "ENSG00000198637"
[17] "PWP2"            "RPL18"           "HIST1H4J"        "HNRNPH2"         "RPS27"           "RELB"            "ACTG1"           "ENSG00000174766"
[25] "RRP9"            "HIST1H4I"        "RPS26"           "DCP2"            "HIST1H4C"        "RPL39"           "UTP11L"          "ENSG00000206212"
[33] "SEC23A"          "RPL37"           "TUBB4"           "MKI67IP"         "ENSG00000196656" "FAU"             "ESF1"            "RPS4X"          
[41] "RPL8"            "BMS1"            "ENSG00000206284" "HSPA5"           "PXN"             "RPL29"           "SNORD33"         "HSPA8"          
[49] "LOC100130702"    "RPL35A"          "SSPO"            "RPL14"           "GSPT2"           "PPP1CB"          "WDR3"            "HIST2H4A"       
[57] "MRPL2"           "PPP1R12A"        "RPS15A"          "RPL26L1"         "DDX49"           "RPL7"            "RCL1"            "ENSG00000187899"

$RPL15P3
[1] "RPL19"           "RPL32P18"        "RPL36AL"         "ENSG00000175333" "RPL15P3"         "RPL18"           "RPL9P7"          "IMPDH1"         
[9] "ENSG00000206212" "ENSG00000096150" "RPS4X"           "RPS15A"          "DDX18"           "DDX24"           "SNORD33"         "RPL27A"         
[17] "LARP2"           "RPF2"            "ENSG00000187899" "RPS7P1"          "PWP1"            "RPL12"           "RPL21P28"        "RPL17P39"       
[25] "RPL15"           "RRS1"            "RPLP2"           "PDCD11"          "DDX54"           "RPL8"            "ENSG00000182498" "RPS25"          
[33] "LOC100130702"    "RPL30"           "CEBPZ"           "SNORD55"         "RBM34"           "HSPA8"           "ATP6V1B2"        "RPL3"           
[41] "RPL4"            "GAR1"            "SNORA70"         "RPS17"           "KPNB1"           "KIAA0020"        "RPL13AP25"       "SNORD21"        
[49] "ENSG00000174766" "RPS5"            "BXDC2"           "DDX3Y"           "SNORD24"         "RPL7P"           "RPL32"           "RPS13"          
[57] "SUMO1P3"         "RPL27"           "RPS7"            "RPS3"            "PES1"            "RPL15P3"         "RPS27A"          "ENSG00000185637"
[65] "ENSG00000212981" "RPL38"           "RPS6"            "NOC3L"           "RPL18AP11"       "ENSG00000138396" "RRP15"           "UBC"   

$RPL19
[1] "ACTG1"           "RPL8"            "RPL15"           "RPS29"           "RPS27"           "TCF12"           "RPL37"           "RPLP2"          
[9] "RPL18"           "ENSG00000096150" "RPL29"           "RPL4"            "HSPA8"           "DDX18"           "LOC100130702"    "ENSG00000182498"
[17] "EXOC2"           "ENSG00000187899" "FTSJ3"           "NOTCH1"          "FAU"             "PXN"             "RPS26"           "RPL14"          
[25] "DYNLL2"          "RPL19"           "ENSG00000198637" "RPL30"           "RPS4X"           "TEX10"           "NIP7"            "RPL12"          
[33] "RPL35A"          "ENSG00000196656" "RPL7"            "RPL26L1"         "PCBP3"           "DHX15"           "RPL17P39"        "RPS12"          
[41] "RPS15A"          "MKI67IP"         "GSPT2"           "SNORD33"         "RRP1B"           "ENSG00000206212" "SNORA70"         "RPL21P28"       
[49] "ENSG00000174766" "RPL39"           "RPL15P3"         "RPL28"           "YARS"            "ENSG00000138396" "ITGA8"           "YWHAZ"          
[57] "KRR1"            "ETF1"            "SNORA62"         "ACTB"            "RPL37A"          "PES1"            "RPS6"            "NOP56"           

>clusters
[1] "ENSG00000206212" "SNORD24"         "ENSG00000187899" "RPLP2"           "RPL15P3"         "RPL19"           "EIF4A1"          "RPS3"           
[9] "RPLP0"           "RPS15"           "ENSG00000196656" "RPL21P28"        "RPS4X"
```

An example of the output I'm looking for is this one:

```
[[1]]
                lineNum count
ENSG00000206212       1     2
SNORD24               2     1
ENSG00000187899       3     1
RPLP2                 4     1
RPL15P3               5     1
RPL19                 6     1
EIF4A1                7     1
RPS3                  8     1
RPLP0                 9     1
RPS15                10     1
ENSG00000196656      11     1
RPL21P28             12     1
RPS4X                13     1

[[2]]
                lineNum count
ENSG00000206212       1     1
SNORD24               2     2
ENSG00000187899       3     1
RPLP2                 4     1
RPL15P3               5     1
RPL19                 6     1
EIF4A1                7     0
RPS3                  8     1
RPLP0                 9     1
RPS15                10     1
ENSG00000196656      11     1
RPL21P28             12     1
RPS4X                13     1

[[3]]
                lineNum count
ENSG00000206212       1     1
SNORD24               2     1
ENSG00000187899       3     2
RPLP2                 4     1
RPL15P3               5     1
RPL19                 6     1
EIF4A1                7     0
RPS3                  8     1
RPLP0                 9     1
RPS15                10     1
ENSG00000196656      11     0
RPL21P28             12     0
RPS4X                13     1
```

I can't post the `dput` of my data because it is too huge, I hope this example is valid for illustration purposes

I'm using the following command line, however it gives me a wrong result because sometimes I get values higher than `1`

```
ll <- lapply(clusters, function(z) data.frame(lineNum=1:length(list1), count=sapply(list1, function(x) sum(str_count(x,z)))))
```

Thanks

UPDATE:

Another example, I hope more clear:

```
>list1
$HSP90AB1
[1] "TALDO1" "ENSG00000130041" "HSP90AB1"  "CLNS1A"  "IMNT"  "CKB"  "RUVBL1"   "NR2E1" "FAM162A"          

$INMT
[1] "COX4I1"   "ME3"      "THUMPD1"  "KLHL8"    "COX4I2"   "KIRREL2"  "HSP90AB1"

$CKB
[1] "THUMPD1"  "SLC12A5"  "NFKB1"    "RPS3"     "ME3"      "ASNA1"    "KLHL8"    "SLC12A4"  "CKM"      "HSP90AB1" "BLOC1S1"  "SERP2"    "ASB9"    

$NR2E1
[1] "GSPT1"    "GSPT2"    "KPNA3"    "HSP90AB1" "EIF2B1"   "TLE4"    

$ME3
[1] "SFRS18" "CKB"    "CKM"    "INMT"  

$FAM162A
[1] "HSP90AA2" "IKBKE"    "HSP90AB1"

$KIRREL2
[1] "INMT"
```

The output looks like this:

```
[[1]]
         lineNum count
HSP90AB1       1     2
INMT           2     1
CKB            3     1
NR2E1          4     1
ME3            5     0
FAM162A        6     1
KIRREL2        7     0

[[2]]
         lineNum count
HSP90AB1       1     1
INMT           2     0
CKB            3     0
NR2E1          4     0
ME3            5     1
FAM162A        6     0
KIRREL2        7     1

[[3]]
         lineNum count
HSP90AB1       1     1
INMT           2     0
CKB            3     0
NR2E1          4     0
ME3            5     1
FAM162A        6     0
KIRREL2        7     0

[[4]]
         lineNum count
HSP90AB1       1     1
INMT           2     0
CKB            3     0
NR2E1          4     0
ME3            5     0
FAM162A        6     0
KIRREL2        7     0

[[5]]
         lineNum count
HSP90AB1       1     0
INMT           2     1
CKB            3     1
NR2E1          4     0
ME3            5     0
FAM162A        6     0
KIRREL2        7     0

[[6]]
         lineNum count
HSP90AB1       1     1
INMT           2     0
CKB            3     0
NR2E1          4     0
ME3            5     0
FAM162A        6     0
KIRREL2        7     0

[[7]]
         lineNum count
HSP90AB1       1     0
INMT           2     1
CKB            3     0
NR2E1          4     0
ME3            5     0
FAM162A        6     0
KIRREL2        7     0
```

But the first element of the output should be composed only with `1s` (element in `clusters` and present in `list1`) or `0s` (no matching), i.e, $HSP90AB1 should be `1` instead of `2`

Comment: If your original data is to large to `dput`, please try to make up a _minimal_, representative toy data set which still captures the important characteristics of your real data.

Comment: I can't follow your question. Can you make this clearer? Eg, you say that " it gives me a wrong result because sometimes I get values higher than 1", but above you say you show "An example of the output I'm looking for", but it contains `2`s. I understand that your real data is too big to post; could you make a small (fake) dataset that is manageable & show what you want?

Comment: I will post another example, @gung my ideal output would be the one I showed but without `1s`

Comment: sorry I'm confused too - "without the 1s"? what about the 0 too in your example?

Comment: Sorry I meant without '2s'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not tested since you did not provide the `dput` for your smaller example, but try this:

```
lapply(list1, function(l, x) {
  tab <- table(l)
  out <- data.frame(lineNum = seq_along(x),
                    count   = ifelse(x %in% names(tab), tab[x], 0L))
  rownames(out) <- x
  out
}, x = clusters)
```

Comment: It works @flodel, but if `clusters` is another list, could I do something like this: `fff <- function(cluster) {
    L <- list1
    lapply(L, function(l, x) {
    tab <- table(l)
    out <- data.frame(lineNum = seq_along(x), count = ifelse(x %in% names(tab), tab[x], 0L))
    rownames(out) <- x
    out
    }, x = cluster)
  }`

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean.

Comment: In my confused example (sorry about that), the object `clusters` is a vector of characters. My question is whether `clusters` was a list composed of different vector of characters instead a single vector, could I use your approach as I've described in my previous comment?

Comment: would the length of the `clusters` list be the same as the length of `list1`, and you'd like to run `clusters[[1]]` against `list1[[1]]`, `clusters[[2]]` against `list1[[2]]`, etc.? If yes, run `Map(function(l, x){...}, list1, clusters)`. If not, what do you want the ouptut to look like given the lengths of `clusters` and `list1`?

Comment: it is the first option, I need to learn more about `Map` function. Thanks a lot again @flodel for your help

Answer (score 1):

I think this is pretty close (though not precisely) what you want. It will work just so long as the names of your list match all of the proteins in the list (so the factors match) - otherwise it will prang.

I edited thecode to show how to deal with an unsorted (by name) list.

**EDIT**

> L=list(B=c("A", "A", "B", "B", "C"), A=c("A", "B", "B", "B", "A"), C= c("B", "C", "B", "B", "C"))
>
> L=L[order(names(L))]

**/EDIT**

> nm=names(L)
>
> lapply(L, function(l)as.data.frame(table(factor(l, levels=nm))))

```
$A
  Var1 Freq
1    A    2
2    B    2
3    C    1

$B
  Var1 Freq
1    A    2
2    B    3
3    C    0

$C
  Var1 Freq
1    A    0
2    B    3
3    C    2
```

Comment: Sorry to reply, @Stephen Henderson, your approach works fine as well, many thanks